# How to do this with routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Say we have a simple resource called news:

```
resources :news
```

The generated paths are in this form `/news/:id`. I would like to provide a shortcut for this by dropping the /news/, so that /1/ goes to news#show with id 1 and the same for all the other resourceful actions of news.

I figured it's probably something along the lines of

```
match '/:id(/:action)', :controller => 'news'
```

but this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the path to a resource use :path =>

```
resources :news, :path => "/"
```

Comment: Cooooooooool. You made me very happy. Here, have a virtual beer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the very bottom of your routes file:

```
match ':id', :to => "news#show"
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing a custom route at the bottom of your routes.rb should work, that will give it lowest priority and allow valid routes to work first:

```
match '/:id', :to => 'news#show'
```

It's important to note that this will basically route anything that wasn't previously caught, and does not exist as an actual static file, to that controller/action. You will want to make sure you render your 404 error page if the news record does not exist.